# Unexpected result from mb_detect_encoding with Windows-1252

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, mb-convert-encoding

I've read Wikipedia's article on [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character encoding.  For characters whose byte value is < 128, it should be the same as ASCII/UTF-8.

This makes sense:

`php -r "var_export(mb_detect_encoding(\"\x92\", 'windows-1252', true));" 
'Windows-1252'`

A left curly apostrophe is detected properly.

`php -r "var_export(mb_detect_encoding(\"a\", 'windows-1252', true));"
false`

Huh?  The letter "a" isn't Windows-1252?

My terminal, where I"m running this, is set to UTF-8.  So that should be the same byte sequence as ASCII for the letter 'a'.  For the sake of minimizing the variables, if I specify the right Windows-1252 byte sequence:

`php -r "var_export(mb_detect_encoding(\"\x61\", 'windows-1252', true));"
false`

Changing the "strict" parameter (which has pretty useless documentation) does nothing in these cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encoding detection is not supported for `windows-1252`.  According to the [mb_detect_order](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-order.php) documentation:

> mbstring currently implements the following encoding detection
> filters. If there is an invalid byte sequence for the following
> encodings, encoding detection will fail.
>
> UTF-8, UTF-7, ASCII,
> EUC-JP,SJIS, eucJP-win, SJIS-win, JIS, ISO-2022-JP
>
> For ISO-8859-*,
> mbstring always detects as ISO-8859-*.
>
> For UTF-16, UTF-32, UCS2 and
> UCS4, encoding detection will fail always.

Comment: Heh, and like an *idiot* I had expected that information to be in the `mb_detect_encoding` documentation!

Comment: Thanks! This is probably also why `mb_convert_encoding` falls back to `ISO-8859-1` if it is specified as a fallback for `windows-1252`, even though the characters in the string are invalid in `ISO-8859-1`. PHP making sense as usual.